# Priority of the executation of two functions with the same name from two different packages

Tags: package, functions

**General question**: two packages have the same name for a certain function. When both packages are installed, which one has the priority to execute that particular function.

**Particular situation**: I am talking about two packages `goto-last-change` and `goto-chg`. The function `goto-last-change` is present in both packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no namespaces in Emacs, all functions are global, therefore the function in the package that was last loaded will override the definition of the other package.

When package A is loaded and defines function `foo`, and then package B is loaded and also defines function `foo`, the `foo` function from package A is totally gone.

Comment: Two packages are both in`.emacs.d\elpa` directory. There is no mention of them in the `.emacs` file, but in `.emacs.d\elpa` directory, there are auto-loaded version of both (`goto-chg-autoloads.el` and `goto-last-change-autoloads.el`).

Comment: In that case, when `package.el` loops over all the autoload files for installed packages, whichever autoload file it hits last will determine which package actually loads when the function is called. Doing `(autoload 'foo "bar") (autoload 'foo "fuz") (foo)` would only load "fuz". I don't know for sure but I would guess it loops over packages alphabetically.

Comment: I am wondering if the developers of packages should care to not choose the names already chosen.  Otherwise there would be many incompatibilities and problems between packages.

Comment: From the looks of it `goto-last-change` is a very old package, and `goto-chg` might be a more modern version of the same functionality. I don't use either but I don't see a reason to have both installed at the same time. This is packages usually prefix all their symbols.